# How can I replace things in minify and css files

Tags: php

I'm using [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

and now I have css file "style.css"

```
body{
    background: url(image.png);
}
```

and when making it mini will be in /path/to/min/dir/f=style.css
because of this I want to make the url of backgound full
something like this

```
body{
    background: url({$url}/image.png);
}
```

and in mimify class make assign or replace just like smarty

to be mimi like this

```
body{background: url(/path/to/image.png);}
```

Comment: You need to do the substitution before you run minify. Minify itself does not support PHP variable substitution AFAIK.

Comment: Related: [CSS Preprocessor or PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9055623/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't minify and have dynamic values in it (it is supposed to be for caching).

If you've got dynamic URL's, do it with inline CSS or add CSS to the header in your html/php file, not in the CSS file

Comment: minify = caching. If you want dynamic URL (with a variable to be replaced by PHP) don't ever put it in a CSS file, but in your HTML

Comment: its not dynamic its just replace the paths

Comment: exactly, that's called dynamic. It's either static or dynamic. If it is static, just type the URL in the CSS

Comment: hhhhh yes but it will be static in the cache

Comment: More to the point, minify isn't for caching so much as any external css is for caching.  The value of an external css file is the browser doesn't have to download it every request, so you'd never want to make an external css file dynamic, minified or not.

Comment: Well... that is caching. Of course minify makes it smaller. But CSS is being cached. Of course, client side, not server side. So what exactly is your point @Umbrella